# Simulating extensible sums with dependent types?

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, functional-programming, dependent-types, abstract-data-types

ML-style languages have a concept of "extensible" or "open" sum types, where variants can be declared at any point, and there's not a fixed number of constructors for the type. They're usually used to model exceptions and handling, where users can declare their own exception types.

I'm wondering, is there a way that we can encode an extensible sum type using dependent types (lacking a primitive for extensible sums?) This seems like the sort of thing we could get away with when we mix types and terms, but I haven't been able to find any references.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this is indeed possible... if you have pattern matching on extensible sums then this is sufficient to encode something akin to nominal type theory: the generation of fresh variants are an effect after all.

Comment: Do you need them to have reasonable run-time behavior?  You could encode "extensible" Sums similar to Hlists (https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) in non-dependent type theories.  If you went with an encoding like that dependent types would make your life easier.